# How to split a string and store each split into variables

Tags: string, bash, cut

```
function check()
{
    word=name@gmail.com
    arr=$(echo $word | tr "@" "\n")

    for x in $arr
    do
        echo "> $x"
    done
}
```

for output I get

```
name
gmail.com
```

I want to store each of them into separate variables. How do I do that?

Do I go

```
for x in $arr
do
    echo "> $x"
    first=$x
    second=$x
done
```

Quite lost here. Help me out please!

Comment: FYI, `function foo() {` is needlessly incompatible with baseline POSIX shells. Just leave out the `function` keyword, and define functions as `foo() { ...`

Comment: Also, `arr` is somewhat misleadingly named, as it isn't actually an array -- bash arrays have their own syntax, and this isn't one of them. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Arrays and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays

Comment: Hey, I don't know what a POSIX shell is. I'm using Linux. And it's working well.
**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the following `read` sentence, in which the `@` is defined as field separator:

```
$ var="name@gmail.com"
$ IFS="@" read var1 var2 <<< "$var"
```

Then see how the values have been stored:

```
$ echo "var1=$var1, var2=$var2"
var1=name, var2=gmail.com
```

---

You can also make use of `cut`:

```
$ name=$(cut -d'@' -f1 <<< "$var")
$ email=$(cut -d'@' -f2 <<< "$var")
$ echo "name=$name, email=$email"
name=name, email=gmail.com
```

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out explicitly that the `read` approach is far more efficient, and should be preferred whenever possible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the comment. To make sure I understand correctly: is it more efficient because it just uses built-ins?

Comment: That, and the avoidance of the fork/exec/read overhead associated with command substitution.

Answer (score 7):

You could use bash [parameter expansion/substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal):

```
$ var="name@gmail.com"

# Remove everything from the beginning of the string until the first
# occurrence of "@"
$ var1="${var#*@}"

# Remove everything from the end of the string until the first occurrence
# of "@"
$ var2="${var%@*}"

$ echo "$var1"
gmail.com

$ echo "$var2"
name
```